# sinon.stub not stubbing original method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

When writing the tests for my following code, `S3resizer`, the stub `S3getStub` seems to not be working when I call `testedModule`, I get the response from mocha `AssertionError: expected stub to have been called at least once, but it was never called`.

Why is `S3resizer_get` not being stubbed?

`s3Handler`:

```
'use strict';

var s3 = new (require('aws-sdk')).S3();

var S3Handler = {};

S3Handler._get = function (bucketName, imgName, callback) {

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imgName
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error, %s", error);
            callback(error, null);
        }
        console.log("good data");
        callback(null, data);
    });
};

module.exports = S3Handler;
```

`S3resizer`:

```
/**
 * This function is called when the protocol defined in index.js is "s3:".
*/

'use strict';

var async = require('async');
var S3 = require("./S3Handler");
var S3get = S3._get;
var S3put = S3._put;
var read = require("./readDirectory");
var readDirFile = read._get;
var readDirCont = read._getContent;
var rs = require("./resizer").resize;
var _sqs = require("./sqsHandler");
var sqsSend = _sqs._sendMessage;

var S3resizer = {};

S3resizer.rs = function (imgName, bucketName) {

S3get(bucketName, imgName, function (error, data) {console.log(data);});
};

module.exports = S3resizer;
```

`tests`:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var extend = require('lodash').extend;
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache();
var url = require('url');
var mockDir = require('mock-fs');

describe("S3resizer", function () {
    var testedModule, fakeResponse, fakeFiles, S3getStub, rsStub, readDirFileStub, readDirContStub, S3putStub, sqsCreateStub, sqsSendStub, cbSpy, callbSpy, imgName, bucketName, sizesObj, imageType, obj;

before(function () {

    S3getStub = sinon.stub();

    rsStub = sinon.stub();

    readDirContStub = sinon.stub();

    readDirFileStub = sinon.stub();

    S3putStub = sinon.stub();

    sqsCreateStub = sinon.stub();

    sqsSendStub = sinon.stub();

    cbSpy = sinon.spy();

    callbSpy = sinon.spy();

    testedModule = proxyquire('../S3resizer', {
        './S3Handler': {
            _get: S3getStub,
            _put: S3putStub
        },
        './readDirectory': {
            _get: readDirFileStub,
            _getContent: readDirContStub
        },
        './resizer': {
            resize: rsStub
        },
        './sqsHandler': {
            _sendMessage: sqsSendStub
        },
    });

    imgName = "Whatever";

    bucketName = "Chappie";

    sizesObj = [
        { width: 800, height: 800, name: 'large' },
        { width: 500, height: 500, name: 'medium' },
        { width: 200, height: 200, name: 'small' },
        { width: 45, height: 45, name: 'thumbnail'}
    ];

    imageType = "png";

    obj = {
        "event":"re-sized",
        "message": {
            "url":"S3://bucketname/images/908798",
            "sizes":["large","medium","small","thumbnail"]
        }
    };

    fakeResponse = {Body: 'image content'};

    fakeFiles = ["thumbnail_Whatever", "small_Whatever", "medium_Whatever", "large_Whatever"];



});

it("calls callback with message 'Done'", function () {
    S3getStub.callsArgWith(2, null, fakeResponse);

    testedModule.rs(imgName, bucketName);
    expect(S3getStub).has.been.called;  
});
```

});

Comment: Try [`@noCallThru`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#preventing-call-thru-to-original-dependency) and see if that causes an error. This will prove that proxyquire is indeed mocking the correct module.

Comment: @Sukima it still calls the original function. Same error.

Comment: Then you have proven that proxyquire is not working as expected. Best to debug that module.

Comment: @Sukima can you see a reason why `proxyquire` would not be working correctly?

Comment: no I can't see anything. I do know my experience with proxyquire has been quite strained. I've recently found better luck with [Mockery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. I had to freshly require the modules under test as to avoid using the cached versions and to refactor the code to use a global override of the require module.

```
describe("S3resizer succesfull call", function () {

    // To avoid having to refactor code with a global override of the require method and using the cached versions from previous tests, freshly require the modules and inject in stubs.
    var S3 = require("../S3Handler");
    var read = require("../readDirectory");
    var _resizer= require("../resizer");
    var _sqs = require("../sqsHandler");

    var testedModule, fakeResponse, fakePutMessage, fakeSqsMessage, fakeFiles, S3getStub, rsStub, readDirFileStub, readDirContStub, S3putStub, sqsSendStub, cbSpy, callbSpy, imgName, bucketName, sizesObj, imageType, obj;

    before(function () {

        S3getStub = sinon.stub(S3, "_get");

        rsStub = sinon.stub(_resizer, "resize");

        readDirContStub = sinon.stub(read, "_getContent");

        readDirFileStub = sinon.stub(read, "_get");

        S3putStub = sinon.stub(S3, "_put");

        sqsSendStub = sinon.stub(_sqs, "_sendMessage");

        cbSpy = sinon.spy();

        callbSpy = sinon.spy();

        testedModule = proxyquire('../S3resizer', {
            './S3Handler': {
                _get: S3getStub,
                _put: S3putStub
            },
            './readDirectory': {
                _get: readDirFileStub,
                _getContent: readDirContStub
            },
            './resizer': {
                resize: rsStub
            },
            './sqsHandler': {
                _sendMessage: sqsSendStub
            }
        });

        imgName = "Whatever";

        bucketName = "Chappie";

        sizesObj = [
            { width: 800, height: 800, name: 'large' },
            { width: 500, height: 500, name: 'medium' },
            { width: 200, height: 200, name: 'small' },
            { width: 45, height: 45, name: 'thumbnail'}
        ];

        imageType = "png";

        obj = {
            "event":"re-sized",
            "message": {
                "url":"S3://bucketname/images/908798",
                "sizes":["large","medium","small","thumbnail"]
            }
        };

        fakeResponse = {Body: 'image content'};

        fakePutMessage = {messageId: "1223abc"};

        fakeSqsMessage = {BinaryValue: "123"};

        fakeFiles = ["thumbnail-Whatever", "small-Whatever", "medium-Whatever", "large-Whatever"];

        S3getStub.callsArgWith(2, null, fakeResponse);

        rsStub.callsArgWith(4, null);

        readDirFileStub.callsArgWith(1, null, fakeFiles);

        readDirContStub.callsArgWith(2, null, fakeResponse);

        S3putStub.callsArgWith(5, null, fakePutMessage);

        sqsSendStub.callsArgWith(1, null, fakeSqsMessage);

        testedModule.rs(imgName, bucketName, sizesObj, imageType, obj, function () {
            cbSpy.apply(null, arguments);
        });
    });

    after(function () {
        S3._get.restore();
        _resizer.resize.restore();
        read._getContent.restore();
        read._get.restore();
        S3._put.restore();
        _sqs._sendMessage.restore();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the fine manual](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#api):

> therefore specify it exactly as in the require statement inside the
>   tested file

You're telling proxyquire to catch require's for `./S3Handler`, where in fact `S3Resizer` is loading `./S3Handler.js` (including `.js`). That's not exactly the same.

Comment: I have changed that as you can see in my original question. I have also changed the test by passing the call to the tested module out of the `before hook`. However it is still not stubbing the module and still tries to call against the actual S3 bucket.

Comment: @hyprstack I've used similar setups which have worked just fine. Ideally, you should boil down your code to a minimal example that is still failing.

Comment: I have reduced my code to a minimal example and have updated my question.

Comment: @hyprstack [here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/3ac703e8038ca0c94e65) is a real minimal example that passes the test.

Comment: Appreciate the example. I see what you mean. Could it be that I'm requiring `S3` in my `S3Handler` that is tripping `proxyquire`?

Comment: @hyprstack no, I went ahead and installed `aws-sdk` and I'm using your original `S3Handler.js` now, and it's getting stubbed just fine. What you could do is gradually adding parts back to the files and see at which point the tests start failing (ie calling the original `_get` instead of the stubbed one).